# "Physical" proof that the medians are concurrent

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, median

Has this simple proof appeared in literature? This is essentially the same proof as one where you call the vertices $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$, and observe that $\frac{\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c}}{3}$ lies on each of the three medians.

Consider the triangle $\bigtriangleup ABC$ with the sides $AB,BC,CA$ having midpoints $D,E,F$ respectively.

Imagine that the triangle is split up into infinitesimally wide strips, each of whose long sides are parallel to the side $AB$. The center of mass of each of these strips lie on the median $CD$. Hence, the center of mass of the entire triangle also lies somewhere on the line $CD$.

By an identical argument, the center of mass of the triangle lies somewhere on the median $AE$ as well as somewhere on the median $BF$.

Thus in fact, all three medians $AE,BF,CD$ have a common point, which is the center of mass of the triangle!

Comment: Yes, I saw it for the first time in a Mir edition of popular science, let me see if I can find/remember the title.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find it and my parents have all the books from when I was a kid. But the book has a drawing of a table with three holes and three strings attached in a common knot, passing through the holes and with weights on the other ends that hand down below the table.

Comment: How is that related to this argument?

Comment: That is the picture in the book. Anyway, don't expect such a well known proof to not have appeared in print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling *triangle median centroid infinitesimal* yields this excerpt from page 69 in the 1917 edition of *Applied Mechanics* by Alfred P. Poorman (highlighting by Google Books):

[image]

The proof doesn't explicitly assert that the medians are concurrent, though it's implied by "Therefore the centroid is on any median". (*Applied Mechanics* is a free ebook!)